# AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1: error when taking modulus of a value using abs() in Impala

Tags: sql, floating-point, impala

I want to take the modulus of a value when using Impala and I am aware of the `abs()` function. When I use this however like such

```
select abs(value) from table
```

It returns a value that is rounded to the nearest integer. The documentation found [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_math_functions.html) states that I need to define the `numeric_type`.  have tried this

```
select abs(float value) from table
```

but this gives me the following error

```
AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1: ... abs(float value) from table ^ Encountered: FLOAT Expected: ALL, CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, DISTINCT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

Any ideas how I set `abs()` to return a `float`?

Comment: Does this work for you? `SELECT cast(Abs(-243.5) as float) AS AbsNum`

Comment: Yes this worked! Would you like to submit it as an actual answer?

Comment: Wasn't sure if Impala had any differences compared with ms sql, but added as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work `SELECT cast(Abs(-243.5) as float) AS AbsNum`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the syntax.  You call the function as `abs(val)`.  The return type is the same as the input type.  It should work on integers, decimals, and floats.

If you want a particular type being returned, then you need to pass in that type, perhaps casting to the specific type.

The documentation is:

> **abs(numeric_type a)**
>
> **Purpose:** Returns the absolute value of the argument.
>
> **Return type:** Same as the input value

Admittedly, this does look like the type should be part of the function call.  But it is really using a programming language-style declaration to show the types that are expected.

Comment: What is different between this and what I have?